# SQLSTATE[42000] [1226] User has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource

Tags: mysql

in my website I am trying to make asynchronous calls to my database with jquery ajax function at least 100 times at the same time in a for loop and after some queries (definitely more than 30) I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000] [1226] User '***' has exceeded the
> 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 30)

but I am using a shared hosting and they say I/they cannot change the max_user_connections value to a higher number.

Now, I have no idea how to solve this problem. Is there anyone who knows a way? Thank you.

**Edit**: I have a website for classification of species/taxonomy and I want to show this in a sunburst chart but there are more than 65K species and it is hard to draw all chart. To achieve this, I made this chart clickable and when an user clicks, new elements are drawn by the response of ajax call.

For simplification, I do not include the lines that I define the variables.

JavaScript:

```js
$.when(info(domain,name)).done((response)=>{
    try {
        layer_info = jQuery.parseJSON(response)
    }catch (error) {
        console.log(response)
        console.log(error)
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < layer_info.size; i++) {

        $.when(info(child_domain,child_name)).done((resp)=>{
            try {
                child_info = jQuery.parseJSON(resp)
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(resp) // I get mentioned error from info.php on console from this line.
                console.log(e)
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Function info makes the ajax call and returns the response.

```js
function info(b,i){
    return $.ajax({
        url: "info.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{domain:b,name:i},
        dataType: "text",
    })
}
```

info.php:

```php
try{
      $timezone = "+3:00";
      $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=***;charset=utf8','***', '***');
      $db->exec("SET time_zone = '{$timezone}'");
      $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage(); // this line generates the error
    }
    try{
      
      $name = $_POST["name"];
      $domain = $_POST["domain"];
      $count_query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE $domain=?");
      $count_query->execute(array($name));
      $count_result = $count_query->fetchColumn();

      $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE $domain=? GROUP BY $sub");
      $query->execute(array($name));
            
      while($results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        array_push($nodes,$results);
      }
    
      $data['spec_size'] = $count_result;
      $data["size"] = count($nodes);
      $data["childs"] = $nodes;
      echo json_encode($data);
    }catch (\Throwable $th) {
      echo $th;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing all of those connections?  We can't answer your question without 1) understanding why you want to make all of those connections and 2) we need to see your code segment that's making these connections

Comment: Reuse connections or make sure you close/exist all connections after done doing the work.  But as devlin mentioned we need more info.

Comment: @devlincarnate i edit the question thank you.

Comment: The obvious answer is to assemble all the `domain/name` pairs into an array and submit the whole lot to your PHP as a single AJAX request. Have PHP work through the list to assemble the results. Probably. a proper query could do this with one call to the database. Some sample data and output would help to pin this down.

Comment: Note that even though you're using prepared statements, your code is still susceptible to SQL injection because you're interpolating the `$domain` variable. Since `$domain` seems to be a column name, you should check it against a whitelist of acceptable columns before using it.